# How to give a result as argument to a ModalRoute class on tap outside of the Modal when barrierDismissible=true in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I would like to return an argument from a ModalRoute class on tap outside of the Modal in Flutter. I think Navigator.pop() is called, but how can I return with a value from the ModalRoute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, found out it is simply add this override to the class

```
@override
T? get currentResult => null;
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/currentResult.html